# XSS in textarea when < and > are not allowed?

Tags: xss, reflected-xss

I am trying to perform XSS on the injection point marked with `XXXX` here:

```
<div>
  <textarea name="billing[something]" id="billing-something" rows="1" 
    type="phone" title="something" placeholder="something" cols="80">
XXXX
  </textarea>      
</div>
```

I can reflect any input, except `<` or `>`. All characters after those will be removed. Can I perform any kind of XSS?

Example:

- If i introduce `XXXX>XXXX` I will obtain `XXXX`
- `XXXX[[>]>///` I will obtain `XXXX[[`
- `XXXX[[<]<///` I will obtain `XXXX[[`

In other places in this application I was able to exploit inputs using payloads like
 `nsehe"onfocus="alert(1)"autofocus="e2c00` because of `<input value="..` fallback.

Comment: have you exhausted this? : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @TheHidden most of them are by defaults fails (becouse of <> ) but yes and also tried diffrent encodings.

Comment: You can't create new tags without angle brackets. If they are always filtered out, then there is no indication this is exploitable.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a lot of other ways you can use XSS, for example you can convert characters to either their hex or ASCII equivalents, an example is here:

```
%3c%73%63%72%69%70%74%3e%61%6c%65%72%74%28%22%48%69%22%29%3b%3c%2f%73%63%72%69%70%74%3e
```

which is the equivalent of an alert box that says hi

```
<script>alert("Hi");</script>
```

EDIT: This blog can be quite useful for bypassing filters: https://alihassanpenetrationtester.blogspot.ie/2013/01/bypassing-xss-filters-advanced-xss.html

Comment: You are assuming that the XSS filter is performed on the query string parameter before it is URL decoded. That is usually not the case.

Comment: also as I told above, encoding I already checked and is not working at all. It just remove the "<" or ">" and the text after it.

Comment: do you haveTried `%3<C` ?